# Kleene star property: proving $(A^+)^* = A^*$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I should prove that $(A^+)^* = A^*$ in a very formal way, any hints?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where did you get stuck?  Do you have any thoughts?  Have you found any examples in your textbook of proving equality of two languages?

Comment: See http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9253/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22540/755 and the dozens of other questions on this site about proving equality of two languages.

Answer (score 2):

When proving $L_1 = L_2$, one common pattern is proving $L_1 \subseteq L_2$ and $L_2 \subseteq L_1$. For proving $L_1 \subseteq L_2$, one common pattern is showing that if $x \in L_1$ then $x \in L_2$. In your case, this means you need to prove two things:

1. If $x \in (A^+)^*$ then $x \in A^*$.
2. If $x \in A^*$ then $x \in (A^+)^*$.

Try to use the definitions of $A^*,A^+,(A^+)^*$.